# WSO2 ESB How can I set input message from localentry?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to create input message into WSO2 ESB config. 
How can i do this?
For example: it may by getting from localentry.

```
<localEntry key="x">
   <a>
      <b>123</b>
   </a>
</localEntry>
```

And I want to copy this XML as input message to `inSequence`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by the use of [`Class Mediator`](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Class+Mediator). So in the referenced custom class you develop for your mediator you can retrieve your local entry and set the payload to its value. [Here](http://vvratha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/accessing-registry-resources-from-class.html) is Ratha's tutorial about retrieving registry resources from within a class. And some code from that same page:

```
// if localentry "testLocalentry" defined in synapse econfig
Entry localEntryObj = (Entry) synapseMsgContext.getConfiguration()
        .getLocalRegistry().get("testLocalentry");
System.out.println(" value: " + localEntryObj.getValue());
System.out.println(" Filename : " + localEntryObj.getFileName());
```

There are probably other ways too. Maybe do a [`Script Mediator`](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator) with Groovy and try to see if you can retrieve the entries in the same way. Setting the payload after that would be one call:

```
mc.setPayloadXML(yourXmlStringWithValueOfLocalEntry);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'am using now        'code'<script language="js"><![CDATA[

               mc.setPayloadXML(<a></a>);
        ]]></script>'code'

Comment: But I have to use get request for the initial message

Comment: @DanStopka: Not sure I understand what you mean. If you need to use the current payload, you have a method available for that too on `mc` reference: `getPayloadXML()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, you need to inject a message in to the ESB using a local entry, but you don't need to send a request to the ESB. For this kind of use case, you can use the Scheduled Tasks[1] functionality of the WSO2 ESB. There you can specify a sequence to execute in a periodical manner. Within that sequence, you can read the message from a local entry and inject in to the message body using the enrich mediator[2].

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Enrich+Mediator